# What is the targetname and the other parameters in the doxygen_add_docs() function in Cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, doxygen

My goal is for cmake to build my program then run Doxygen.
I have a simple autogenerated cmake file from Qt.

The Cmake runs, but it never generates the Doxygen documentation. I also have the `Doxyfile` there too. Both were created by the Doxywizard, and they work when I use the doxywizard tool, but not with the Cmake file.
My output is set to `docs`

There are no errors, however Doxygen documentation is never generated.

```
find_package(Doxygen)
if (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
    set(DOXYGEN_GENERATE_HTML YES)
    doxygen_add_docs(targetName
        [filesOrDirs...]
        [ALL]
        [USE_STAMP_FILE]
        [WORKING_DIRECTORY dir]
        [COMMENT comment])
endif()
```

This is method on the Cmake documentation to make the Doxygen documentation, using the Cmake command (`doxygen_add_docs`), however I have no idea what the targetname is and what the format is for using the parameters. Is it possible for the function to use an existing Doxyfile?

Thanks

Comment: You have an attempt and it probably gives you some error or other unexpected result. Please, add this error into the question post so we will be able to help you in fixing it.

Comment: You should read the documentation for CMake's own Doxygen support: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindDoxygen.html

Comment: @AlexReinking Do you know of any examples with the `doxygen_add_docs` ? I recently just got into using Cmake having used Qmake, and am not great with the syntax yet. Also with that method, are you allowed to use your own Doxyfile?

Comment: I wrote this for the Halide project: https://www.github.com/halide/Halide/tree/master/doc/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: `using the Cmake command` What command are you using exactly? Are you running the target `doxygen`? `doxygen_add_docs(targetName
    [filesOrDirs...]
    [ALL]` - do you understand what `ALL` means and what is a "default build target"?

Comment: @KamilCuk The `default build target` method. honestly I don't understand what how ` doxygen_add_docs(targetName     [filesOrDirs...]     [ALL]` works, I assume ALL is generate documents for everything?

Comment: `The default build target method` Please post the command you execute.

Comment: @KamilCuk I don't know what that is, I only started learning about Cmake and Doxygen recently